# Can I extend Google Blogger to include text folding capabilities to hide or show a text block, or to recreate Blogger editor using Atom?

Tags: html, editor, atom-editor, blogger

I like the Google Blogger editor for composing rich text posts for my blogs, but I also need the missing capability to hide / show text blocks easily, possibly in a nested fashion, such as the folding capability of the Atom editor.  It would be even better if I could then rearrange the folded text blocks as I could in an outliner product.

My end-goal is to be able to post on Blogger documents that have a drill-down capability for hiding or revealing successive levels of detail.   I'm willing to create these documents outside of Blogger and then copy / paste the HTML into Blogger by hand in order to post them.

I can find html snippets and widgets that insert a single-level toggle button to hide or show a block of text, but they all require leaving composer mode and diving into the html code itself, which is awkward and distracting and error-prone. I want to just highlight a block of text and click some "fold" button on the editor and have that text folded for me or my colleagues.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I could accomplish this?    Is there a way to extend the Blogger editor to include a folding capability?   Is there a way to recreate the Blogger editor in Atom where some included package could provide that capability?    Am I looking up the wrong tree entirely and missing an existing off-the-shelf editor for blog posts that has both the capabilities of the Blogger editor and a native folding capability?  It does not have to be a free product.

Thank you in advance for any ideas or suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:**
I would probably write or modify a blogger theme to hide the post body text by default, intercept and process the text with JavaScript - wrapping the paragraphs in show\hide blocks, then show the post body content when it's all ready to go.

**Extra Detail:**
The Google Blogger admin control panel can't be modified. It's not like WordPress or Umbraco. It's hosted on Google's servers, it's closed propriety code, and they don't provide a way to modify the user interface.

There is the possibility of using a Widget but that wouldn't allow you to work from the Blogger's Post editor interface, plus these have been locked down recently so you can only use official widgets or custom HTML\JavaScript.

To my knowledge there are no external blogger editors currently available (Blogger for Word was discontinued).

I don't use Atom but I think it very unlikely you'll find a plugin for that or another editor, such as Visual code, that does what you want.

However, to upload content from Atom or Visual Code or similar you could write a plugin\extension to process the text and upload the required HTML using Blogger's REST API.